# Set Image of UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I currently have a UITableView that holds a list of events. Each event has a button where the user can press it to get access to a larger view of a photo associated with the event. I have the UIButton connected and set up but I'm having a hard time setting the image in the new window. Here is my function:

```
func largeMap(sender: UIButton!) {
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("largeMapView", sender: self)
    println(sender.tag.description)
    println(documentsPath+"/Flight"+(sender.tag.description)+"/Map.png")
    if let image = UIImage(data: manager.contentsAtPath(documentsPath+"/Flight"+(sender.tag.description)+"/Map.png")!) {
        largeMapView.image = image
    }
}
```

When I run the app, it crashes at largeMapView.image = image and gives me "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I've checked and the path for the image is correct and it is accessing the image but it's not able to set it to the UIImageView. I have the UIImageView  outlet set at the top of the class. Why is this happening? I've set UIImageView's in this manner before but it just won't work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the problem is that you are using exclamation marks. Exclamation marks are never safe! They can be a "bad smell", a danger signal - and in your code, that's just what they are.

(1)

> I have the UIImageView outlet set at the top of the class.

But you do not show *how* it is set. You do not show what `largeMapView` is or how it is declared. The declaration might look like this:

```
@IBOutlet var largeMapView : UIImageView!
```

If so, that is bad - that is an implicitly unwrapped optional, which means it might be nil. This could be the source of your problem. By using a conditionally unwrapped optional you are covering up the problem - until you try to set into nil, and then you crash. If it is never being set properly, that's the reason for the crash.

(2)

Along the same same lines, the rest of your code, too, should not force-unwrap Optionals (using `!` postfix operator) unless you know for *certain* that they can never be nil. Rewrite like this so that every Optional is unwrapped conditionally and safely:

```
if let d = manager.contentsAtPath(documentsPath+"/Flight"+(sender.tag.description)+"/Map.png") {
    if let image = UIImage(data: d) {
        largeMapView.image = image
    }
}
```

This way, if `contentsAtPath` fails or `UIImage(data:)` fails, nothing will happen - you won't set your image - but at least you won't crash. And you can use stepping in the debugger to figure out where you *are* failing. - But even this will not save you if the problem is that `largeMapView` is a nil implicitly unwrapped Optional.

Comment: I implement the safe unwrapping as you suggested. Upon running the app it safely unwraps the image but still gets to the end and crashes on 'largeMapView.image = image' and says that it unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional which leads me to question the outlet I've made.

Comment: Correct. That is why _I_ question the outlet. I believe that your crash is purely diagnostic; your _real_ problem is that your outlet is not being set. But that would be a different issue! I believe I've answered the question you actually posed, i.e. why you are crashing in the first place.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I'll have to keep working at it until I fix my issue. If you have any thoughts if be happy to hear them!

Comment: Why should I have thoughts? What I have is skepticism. I have no reason to believe that `d` (in my code) is not nil, that `image` is not nil, or that `largeMapView` is not nil. You tell _me_ why you think they should not be nil. If you think you know which one is nil, then ask a new question about that, now that I have shown you how to localize the issue down to one of them. But _this_ question, I believe, is completely answered.

Comment: I am sorry to have offended you. You bring up a valid point and I thank you for that. I'll mark the answer as such. I ended up just creating a separate class for the pop up and passing the image path in a 'prepareForSegue' method. Have a great weekend!

Comment: Furthermore I hadn't seen your latest edit and I appreciate the additional explanation. That makes a lot of sense thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I do tend to write in several passes.